# Armadillo C++ and BLAS and ATLAS cannot find lapack blas under mingw32

Tags: c++, lapack, blas, mingw32, armadillo

All,

Summary ...

I am trying to compile example.cpp of 
  arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#example_prog

I try to compile and link armadillo with lapack and blas.
I am always getting the same error back.
This message is returned

```
ld.exe: cannot find -llapack
ld.exe: cannot find -lblas
```

I verified that all of my paths below are correct and ran the following.

```
g++ example.cpp -o example -O1  -I..\..\lapackblas_headers\lapack -I..\..\lapackblas_headers\blas  -I..\include
```

-L....\lapackblas_MD_debug -llapack -lblas

This message is returned

```
ld.exe: cannot find -llapack
ld.exe: cannot find -lblas
```

FROM

```
f:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llapack
f:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lblas
```

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Andre Mikulec
Andre_Mikulec@Hotmail.com

Details follow ...

I downloaded pre-compiled versions of LAPACK and BLAS were downloaded from ...
  http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xsvobod2/misc/lapack/

I am following the instructions here

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/arma/files/latest/download
http://sourceforge.net/projects/arma/files/armadillo-3.800.0.tar.gz
file:///M:/YDrive/All_Economics/eclipse_workspace/armadillo-3.800.0/README.txt
```

From

arma.sourceforge.net/download.html#windows

I have lapack and blas libraries

```
ls -alrt ../../lapackblas-MD-debug

-rw-r--r--  1 Administrator Administrators   27092 Oct  5  2009 blas_win32_MDd.lib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Administrator Administrators  280576 Oct  5  2009 blas_win32_MDd.dll
-rw-r--r--  1 Administrator Administrators  254886 Oct  5  2009 lapack_win32_MDd.lib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Administrator Administrators 3774464 Oct  5  2009 lapack_win32_MDd.dll
drwxr-xr-x  2 Administrator Administrators       0 Mar  3 08:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 Administrator Administrators       0 Mar  3 08:06 ..

ls -alrt ../../lapackblas_headers/blas

MANYFILES.h

ls -alrt ../../lapackblas_headers/lapack

MANYFILES.h

ls -alrt ../include
```

MANYFILES.h

I try to compile and link armadillo with lapack and blas.
I am always getting the same error back.

```
M:
cd \YDrive\All_Economics\eclipse_workspace\armadillo-3.800.0\examples

M:\YDrive\All_Economics\eclipse_workspace\armadillo-3.800.0\examples>
```

I tried relative paths

```
g++ example.cpp -o example -O1  -I..\..\lapackblas_headers\lapack -I..\..\lapackblas_headers\blas  -I..\include 

-L..\..\lapackblas_MD_debug -llapack -lblas
```

I tried absolute paths

```
g++ example.cpp -o example -O1  -IM:\YDrive\All_Economics\eclipse_workspace\lapackblas_headers\lapack  

-IM:\YDrive\All_Economics\eclipse_workspace\lapackblas_headers\blas  

-IM:\YDrive\All_Economics\eclipse_workspace\armadillo-3.800.0\include 

-LM:\YDrive\All_Economics\eclipse_workspace\lapackblas_MD_debug -llapack -lblas
```

In all cases returned information is here

```
ld.exe: cannot find -llapack
ld.exe: cannot find -lblas

f:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llapack
f:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lblas
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.
Andre Mikulec
Andre_Mikulec@Hotmail.com

Comment: `-L....\lapackblas_MD_debug -llapack -lblas `  You're missing a `\\`.  Is this just a typo in your post?

Comment: That is not my typo.  That is the web page performing some magic that removed my slash as I pasted the code.  Here is my original command: g++ example.cpp -o example -O1  -I..\..\lapackblas_headers\lapack -I..\..\lapackblas_headers\blas  -I..\include 

-L..\..\lapackblas_MD_debug -llapack -lblas    No typo exists "-L..\..\lapackblas_MD_debug"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the partial solution.

```
g++ -o example example.cpp ..\..\lapackblas_MD_debug\blas_win32_MDd.dll ..\..\lapackblas_MD_debug\lapack_win32_MDd.dll -O1  -I..\..\lapackblas_headers\lapack -I..\..\lapackblas_headers\blas  -I..\include
```

This page explains it.
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs

Basically, I needed to specify the DLL files directly on the command line after the main program

Also, to FINISH TO SOLUTION, I have to install the (yet) dependent DLLs
from an Intel Fortran compiler ( or 30 day eval ).

This page ( were I aquired the DLLs ) explains it ( in the fine print ).

```
LAPACK & BLAS precompiled binaries for Win32 platform
http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xsvobod2/misc/lapack/
```